# How can any sentence be valid?

Tags: logic, model-theory, formal-languages, foundations

I've just started working through C. Chang and H. Keisler's *Model Theory* independently right now, and I'm reading through the first chapter, but I'm a little confused by the nature of a valid sentence. So suppose we have language, $\mathscr{S}$, and a sentence built from these, $\varphi$. According to the text, we say that $\models\varphi$ if and only if $$\forall A\subseteq \mathscr{S},A\models \varphi$$
However, earlier the text also says,

> Two distinguished models are the empty set $\emptyset$ and the set $\mathscr{S}$ itself.

It seems to me that this implies that no $\varphi$ may be valid then, as $$\nexists \varphi,\emptyset\models\varphi$$
due to the fact that there are no sentence symbols from which to construct any $\varphi$. Is it the case then that no sentence ever valid in our model theory of sentential logic? In which case why do we even care about validity? Or is it to be inferred that in defining validity we must ignore the empty model?

Comment: For example $\varnothing \models (P \to P)$ if language $\mathscr S$ admits at least one wff $P$.

Comment: @RobArthan I'm aware, but the problem here is that it can't be the case that any sentence is valid, as that would imply that the $\emptyset$ (as a subset of $\mathscr{S}$) models $\varphi$. The existence of other models is irrelevant here.

Comment: @tox123: $\varnothing$ isn’t a model for any sentence symbol, but it **is** a model for some sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be a sentence symbol, and let $\varphi$ be $\neg S$; then $\varnothing\not\vDash S$, since $S\notin\varnothing$, so $\varnothing\vDash\varphi$.

Comment: I completely missed that last condition of validity, oops. Thanks!

Comment: @tox123: You’re welcome!